# postgres select non existing field as empty string

Tags: sql, postgresql

This might be a stupid question. Imaging following table in Postgres:

```
create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein');
```

A simple select of all fields:

```
select  id, firstname, lastname   scientist;
```

results in:

| is | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | einstein |

Is there some way to add a kind of non-existing empty virtual field f.e. age?
Pseudo Code:

```
 select 
    id, 
    firstname, 
    lastname,
    age as '' -- my non existing field that should show up in the results
    from 
    scientist;
```

that the result looks like?

| is | firstname | lastname | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | einstein |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the other way round: `as` defines a column alias, so

```
'' as age
```

will work.

However, I'd be quite surprised about a column named `age` in a result that is a character value, not an integer. If you want a typed value, you can also use `null::int as age`